# How to pass an object from an intent to onActivityResult() method

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to create an uninstaller application, so far everything is OK, but here is the problem: I want to refresh the list of apps after uninstall, this is what I came up with:

```
private void uninstallApps(List<Apps> apps) {
for (AppModel app : apps) {
    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", app.getPackageName(), null);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE, uri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
}
```

Then

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

How can I pass the "app" variable from uninstallApps() to onActivityResult()?

Comment: i did not understand your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will not get the package detail while `startActivityForResult` with `Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE`,

In extra with your intent if your set `Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT` like below, you will get `android.intent.extra.INSTALL_RESULT` in the `onActivityResult, but we should care in this situation also, because if the user didn't uninstall the app then we will get null value in intent, So we should check null for intent data every time.

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
```

If you want to refresh your list based on the uninstall of the any app, Best place is Broadcast receiver

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
```

If you add this filter in your broadcast, you will get the broadcast, in that you can get the package details of the uninstall Apps.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String packageName = intent.getData().getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart();

    Log.d("", "onReceive: " + intent.getAction());
    Log.d("", "onReceive: " + packageName);

    // If the action is android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED then app is uninsatalled
    if (intent.getAction().equals( "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")) {

        // Here you send one local broadcast to your activity or fragment and you can update in your view.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I pass the "app" variable from uninstallApps() to onActivityResult()?

You store it it in a field on your activity or fragment class, wherever you are calling `startActivityForResult()` and expecting the `onActivityResult()` callback.

Comment: I tried that, but the problem is that all the intents are executed first then all the corespondent onActivityResult() methods, so every time I store the app in a field, it overwritten in the next iteration of the for loop

Comment: @ToniJoe: "is that all the intents are executed first" -- change your code to only start the next `ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE` activity after the previous one has completed.

Comment: That is the problem, the for loop executes the intents first, I'm struggling the whole day it's really annoying.

Comment: @ToniJoe: "the for loop executes the intents first" -- and, as I wrote, change that. Get rid of the `for` loop. Execute *one* `startActivityForResult()` call. In `onActivityResult()`, in addition to whatever else you are trying to do, call `startActivityForResult()` for the next one. And so on. You did not write the `ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE` activity; you cannot force it to somehow return something to you.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks CommonsWare. you saved my day.